# Multiple Conventional Routes order Precedence not working as expected for (Current LTS version ASP.NET CORE 3.1 )

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

This question is related to ASP.NET Core Routing. I am doing the hands-on implementation (ASP.NET CORE 3.1 LTS) of Concept  **Multiple Conventional Routes.**
MS documentation [MultipleConventional Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#multiple-conventional-routes)

> According to documentation, conventional routing is order-dependent. what that means is there are consequences for not ordering my routes correctly.

here is the code snippet of the app.UseEndpoint method with a list of configured routes.

```
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {        

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "CustomerHomepage",
                defaults:new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index" },
                pattern: "customer/{name}/index"); });
```

For this request  https://localhost:44341/customer/sean/details

At first look at the set of route templates and order especially the first route it is a perfect match
with

controller name = customer

action name = sean

id = details.

what I have in the project.

- I do have a controller name Customer but no action name as sean instead I have action name as details inside the Customer Controller.

**Question**
The point I am trying to make is this path **customer/sean/details** overall should be invalid and should not navigate anywhere based on the order of the routing template.
Instead, it does navigate to the action method Details in the customer controller. The question is why it is working instead it should not be based on the concept that conventional routing is order-dependent and this request URL customer/sean/details match to the first route. Also, what would be the best example for this claim that conventional routing is order-dependent.

The code for the Customer Controller is listed down

```
public class CustomerController: Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Details(string name) {

        ViewBag.CustomerName = name;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention based routing in ASP.NET Core 3.x+ is *not* fundamentally order based. Instead, the routing system builds an acyclic graph which is used to match the incoming URL to the **best** route. In your example, the literal match to `customer` makes the send route the best match.

In [this series](https://andrewlock.net/visualizing-asp-net-core-endpoints-using-graphvizonline-and-the-dot-language/) I describe how you can visualize all the routes in your ASP.NET Core applications, which may help you to understand how routes are combined.

[image]

Comment: Hi - so, does it mean that what is written here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conventional-routing-order (e.g. `Conventional routing is order-dependent`) is only applicable to (probably rare) incidents where two routes have achieved the same **precedence** score? I gotta say the docs could be a bit clearer about that, if you read the first link I posted and the part about precedence - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-template-precedence-and-endpoint-selection-order

Answer (score 0):

From [this doc about "Routing in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-concepts), you would find the process of matching an incoming request to an endpoint, like below.

*URL matching operates in a configurable set of phases. In each phase, the output is a set of matches. The set of matches can be narrowed down further by the next phase. The routing implementation does not guarantee a processing order for matching endpoints. **All** possible matches are processed at once. The URL matching phases occur in the following order. ASP.NET Core:*

1. *Processes the URL path against the set of endpoints and their route templates, collecting **all** of the matches.*
2. *Takes the preceding list and removes matches that fail with route constraints applied.*
3. *Takes the preceding list and removes matches that fail the set of [MatcherPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.matcherpolicy) instances.*
4. *Uses the [EndpointSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.matching.endpointselector) to make a final decision from the preceding list.*

*The list of endpoints is prioritized according to:*

- *The [RouteEndpoint.Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeendpoint.order)*
- *The [route template precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rtp)*

*All matching endpoints are processed in each phase until the [EndpointSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.matching.endpointselector) is reached. The `EndpointSelector` is the final phase. It chooses the highest priority endpoint from the matches as the best match. If there are other matches with the same priority as the best match, an ambiguous match exception is thrown.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Fei. I have already looked into this documentation before posting the question and was not able to come to conclusion why it is actually working when it should not.